# Tensor analysis - Index Notation

Tags: tensors

Are there some good tutorials (.nb files) about Tensor analysis using **index notation** built in to ***Mathematica***?

An example of a typical index notation:

$$C_{i j k l} = \lambda \delta_{i j} \delta_{k l} + \alpha \delta_{i k} \delta_{j l} + \beta \delta_{i l} \delta_{j k}$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Mathematica, [symbolic tensors](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SymbolicTensors) don't necessarily use indices. Instead, tensors are declared to have a certain number of indices (rank):

```
$Assumptions = A ∈ Arrays[{d, d}];
```

The above code asserts that `A` is a tensor of rank 2 where each index is of dimension `d`. For your example, let:

```
id4 = TensorProduct[IdentityMatrix[d], IdentityMatrix[d]];
```

The tensor `id4` corresponds to your $\lambda \delta_{i j} \delta_{k l}$ term. Your other tensors are just transposed versions:

$\alpha \delta_{i k} \delta_{j l}$:

```
TensorTranspose[id4, {1,3,2,4}]
```

$\beta \delta_{i l} \delta_{j k}$:

```
TensorTranspose[id4, {1, 4, 2, 3}]
```

So, Mathematica would represent your tensor equation as:

```
c = λ id4 + α TensorTranspose[id4, {1,3,2,4}] + β TensorTranspose[id4, {1,4,2,3}];
```

If you use an explicit dimension, then the above code would be represented using indices of an array. As an example, let the dimensions be $d=3$, and check that the above equation sets the indices of `c` to the correct values:

```
d = 3;
c[[1, 2, 1, 2]]
c[[1, 1, 2, 2]]
c[[1, 2, 2, 1]]
```

> α
>
> λ
>
> β

Comment: thanking you! but in this case I only want to use index notation in mathematica, it should be helpful in some cases. Thanks you for your understanding!

Comment: Dear all. I only want to use build-in, not third part. If I search such topics in google, most are third part tool in mathematica.

Comment: @FEAPMAN TensorProduct and TensorTranspose are the built-in symbols that one can use with tensors. They are not from a third party package.